# C: Need to pause a process until sigalrm

Tags: c, linux, process, signals

I have a problem with this code..

I need to put in wait (`sigwait`) a process until arrive two Signals `SIGUSR1`/`SIGUSR2` (maybe I can use `sigalrm` to catch the signals?)

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    sigset_t set;
    int sig;

    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR2);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
    sigwait(&set, &sig);
    printf("Got signal %d\n", sig);
    /*need to set Sigalrm?*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to wait until you get *both* signals? Or just one of the two?

Comment: It's not important if arrive sigusr1 or sigusr2, just one of those..thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pass `select()` the read end of a pipe. When you catch the signal, write to the pipe. This will cause `select()` to return and execution to continue.